# Counterexample for closed graph theorem in unmetrizable case

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Consider locally convex vector spaces $X,Y$ and let $A: X\to Y$ be a linear operator with closed graph. Closed Graph Theorem states that if $Y$ is Fréchet then $A$ is continuous.

What is a counterexample to this in the case when $Y$ is not Fréchet?

EDIT: Thank you very much for your comments and shots!;)
My question was of course about a counterexample where $X$ is "good" (let it be barrelled).

Comment: The Closed Graph Theorem requires some conditions on $X$ as well, e.g. that it is a barrelled space.  Otherwise, for a counterexample take any closed unbounded (partially defined) operator $A$ in a Banach space $Y$, 
and let $X = {\mathscr D}(A)$ with the topology of $Y$.

Comment: Robert, you shot first! ;-)

Comment: In Proposition 4.13 and Example 4.14 of that paper:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612398.pdf
you have a very explicit counter-example to the open mapping theorem, where $X$ is a (non-separable) Hilbert space, $Y$ is locally convex, and $A:X\rightarrow Y$ is linear continuous, bijective, with non-continuous inverse.

Comment: For an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $X$ consider $Y=X$ endowed with the *finest locally convex topology* and the identical map. On the other hand, if the domain $X$ is *ultrabornologial* the closed graph theorem holds for so-called *webbed spaces* introduced by de Wilde. This is a very large class of locally convex spaces which contains all Banach spaces and is stable w.r.t. closed subspaces, separated quotients, and countable products and direct sums. See, e.g., *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.